# Why my React [this.props] contains no element necessary for parameter capturing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react class and I am trying to retrieve the parameters from the caller. As refer to a few online tutorials and also those answers from the Stackoverflow, I should use either the below:

- this.props.match.params
- queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);

However when I try to compile it with my node.js, both approaches also throws me error as below:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./js/module/sample/sample01.tsx:8:29
>       TS2339: Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./js/module/sample/sample01.tsx:9:44
>       TS2339: Property 'location' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'.

Its seems no further element is under this **this.props**

Here is my source code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as queryString from 'query-string';

export class Textboxes extends React.Component {

  render() {
    var firstName = this.props.match.params.firstName;
    var parsed = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
    var firstName = parsed.firstName;
    var lastName = parsed.lastName;
    return(
    ...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to get the parameters passed to Textboxes...

```
<Textboxes firstName="John" lastName="Wong/>
```

All you should have to do is...

```
export class Textboxes extends React.Component {

  render() {
    var firstName = this.props.firstName;
    var lastName = this.props.lastName;
    return(
    ...
```

If that's wrong, let me know and I'll remove this post.

Comment: hi JD, using this.props.firstName yield similar error as well during compilation. <br>ERROR in [at-loader] ./js/module/sample/sample01.tsx:8:29
    TS2339: Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<{}>'.

Comment: Just curious, I see that you have a *.tsx extension.  Are you working with typescript of jsx?

Comment: I'm not exactly an expert in typescript, but this might be your issue...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489338/reactjs-typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-child-component?rq=1

Comment: hi JD, yes its typescript of jsx. For the link you shared, it seems to tackle the issue on child component, but mine is not a child component :)